# How to get .apk file's icon in ios?

Tags: ios, apk

For now, I can read a `.apk` file from sandbox in my iOS Project, but I want to show more detailed information about this Android package file, like the package name or icon in `UITableView`. How can I access this information to make my model?

Answer (score 0):

.apk file is a zip archive and its manifest file will be in binary format. If you extract the apk file and read its manifest file from binary format, you can read package information, permissions and icon name(which will be located in drawable folder).

In Android platform, there are API's to read package information of apk files. In IOS they are not available.